# how to create collapsible and expandable panel in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I need to create a collapsible and expandable panel in Java Swing.. I am not able to find it in the DESIGN PALETTE of Netbeans 7.4 .. Kindly help me

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/341737/GUI/java/Expand-Collapse-Panels or http://just4everythings.blogspot.com/2013/06/swing-accordion-pane-or-swing.html

Comment: Check http://eppleton.de/blog/?p=970

Comment: Take a look for SwingX JXCollapsiblePane

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JavaFX` has a `JFXPanel` class which allows you to embed JavaFX components in Swing. Using that, you can embed the `TitledPane` and `Accordion` controls into your Swing application.

Your end result will be like this:
[image]

This is exactly what you need, isn't it ? =)
This saves you a lot of coding work.

Tutorial on how to work with these JavaFX components is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/accordion-titledpane.htm  and
embedding of JavaFX nodes in Swing is here: [How to add JFXPanel to already existing swing app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171316/how-to-add-jfxpanel-to-already-existing-swing-app/20179104#20179104)